# Structured Light - How to do when the projector's resolution is lower than patterns?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, gray-code

I try to build a structured light environment to do 3D scanning.

As far as I know, if I choose to use gray code to reconstruct a 3D model, I have to implement specific patterns that were encode in power 2(2^x, x = 0 ~ 10).

[image]

That is said, the patterns must be at least 1024 x 1024 in resolution.

What if my DLP projector only support resolution up to 800 x 480? It projects Moire pattern when the gray code pattern resolution becomes too high(I tried). What should I do?

My friends suggest that I create 1024 x 1024 patterns, and "crop" them into 800 x 480,

but I thought the gray code should follow specific sequence and patterns, my friends suggestion will create several image that is not symmetry.

Does anyone have the same experience like me?

----------2015.8.4 Update Question----------

I was thinking that if my projector can't perfectly projects high resolution patterns, can I just let it projects the patterns with low resolution, for instance, from 2^0 to 2^6?

Or the gray code strictly demands patterns from 2^0 to 2^10? Otherwise gray code is not available?

Comment: Crop to 800x480, do not rescale. I don't think that the missing area will be an issue (unless your software demands the 1024 stripes, which I doubt).

Comment: Also check that your lens is good enough to sustain that spatial frequency (MTF curve). An what about your scanner/camera resolution ?

Answer (score 3):

**you can not directly scale down to your resolution**

because it would distort the pattern make it useless

instead you can:

1. **crop it to your resolution**

   but you need to handle that in the scanning part too because you would not have the full pattern available
2. **use nearest usable power of 2 resolution**

   like `512x256` and create pattern for it. The rest of the space is unused (wasting pixels)
   [image: 512x256]
3. **use bullet #2 + scale up to fit your resolution better**

   so create pattern `512x256` and linearly scale to fit to `800x480` as much as you can so:

   ```
   800/512 = 1.5625
   480/256 = 1.8750
   ```

   use the smaller scale (`512x256 * 1.5625 -> 800x400`) so scale the pattern by `1.5625` and use that as a pattern image

   [image: 800x400]

   this is scaled by nearest neighbor to avoid subpixel grayscale colors which are harder to detect. **This will waste less pixels but it can lower the precision of 3D scan !!!**

**This is how I generate my pattern in C++ and VCL:**

```cpp
// [generate pattern xs*ys power of 2 resolution]
// clear buffer
bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));
int x,y,a,da;
for (da=0;1<<da<xs;da++);                   // number of bits per x resolution
for (a=0,y=0;y<ys;y++,a=(y*da)/ys)
 for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
  if (int((x>>a)&1)==0) pyx[ys-1-y][x]=0x00FFFFFF;
bmp->SaveToFile("3D_scann_pattern0.bmp");
```

- `bmp` is VCL bitmap
- `xs,ys` is the resolution of a bitmap
- `p[ys][xs]` is direct 32bit pixel access to bitmap

**This is slight differently encoded then your pattern !!!**

**[Notes]**

- If you need precision use bullet #2
- If you need to cover bigger area use bullet #3
- You can also scale in `y` axis differently then in `x` axis as this is just 1D encoding

Comment: I suppose you mean "projector's resolution" in the first line and bullet 1, right? or you mean my PC(NB) resolution?

Comment: @APU yes of coarse projectors resolution ... visualization device has nothing to do with scanning. The only resolutions you have to mind are projectors and camera(s) ...